# How can I acquire a permission in java?

Tags: java, windows, security, file, permissions

By that I mean showing that Windows popup "Do you wish to allow this program to modify your computer?" so I can write files.

Comment: Standalone application or Web application ?

Comment: Did you try ... opening a file for writing?

Comment: IvanDonat's comment: "You need to explain someone thing before I can answer: We need to know do you already have permission to write and you just want to check if user wants that or you want to write in, lets say C:/WINDOWS/ and you don't have permission to write there."

Comment: It's a standalone application. In Windows 7, when my application is running on C:/Program Files/Some folder/myapp.jar, and I try to create a new File or modify existing ones, I get an Access Denied exception.